# Entering a string with over 900,000+ characters

Tags: ruby

Using 'gets' only uses like half (or less) of the entered string. Is there a way to load the string? (It's 900,000+ characters long)

Comment: Where is it stored? I'm sure you are not typing 900000 characters in terminal.

Comment: It's a copy paste into the terminal @JagdeepSingh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to work around this limitation of `gets` is to store that 900k character string into a file and then use `File.read` to read it:

```
very_long_string = File.read("./900k_chars")
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!